# How do I Implement AUTO_INCREMENT in a Yii2 Migration Using MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have created a yii2 (v2.0.6) migration for a simple MySQL (v5.6.21) table. Everything works, except that I cannot figure out how to AUTO_INCREMENT the primary key. The problem seems to be that I am using a small integer rather than the more standard long integer datatype. Here is my migration code:

```
$this->createTable('{{%status}}', [
    'id' =>          $this->smallInteger(8)->unique(),
    //'id' =>        $this->primaryKey(11),
    'description' => $this->string(20),
]);

$this->addPrimaryKey('','status','id');
```

I could get around the problem by using the ->primaryKey() method, which is commented out in line 3 above, but then yii creates a long integer datatype, and I am trying to avoid that. Any insight into the problem will be much appreciated.

Comment: This forum thread might be useful to you: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/8945-auto-increment/page__view__findpost__p__73966

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it is critical to have that column type, you can always change it:

```
$this->createTable('{{%status}}', [
    'id'          => $this->primaryKey(11),
    'description' => $this->string(20),
]);
$this->alterColumn('{{%status}}', 'id', $this->smallInteger(8).' NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT');
```

(I've tested this with MySQL - it works)

However, like @scaisEdge says, it's usually not worth the troble.

Answer (score 5):

Why not a simply primaryKey?, the format for integer(8) , integer(11) or primary key is always the same  is always an integer long 
then or you need a small int (max  5 digit) or you can use  the normal `$this->primaryKey()` because

SMALLINT is for    storage of 2  byte (value -32768    32767) an then
`smallInteger(8)`  is not coherent.  the numer 8 is for output not for store format. If you want  8 digit you  need at least 
INT of 4 byte   -2147483648 2147483647  or more

Comment: A downside to `primaryKey()` is the uncertainty which datatype you get. This is problematic once you want to create foreign key as the referencing column must be of the same type. Do you have any suggestions how to circumvent this problem?

Comment: @DBX12   your comment is not clear  to  . me .. in Yii2 the default primary key data type is integer .. but you can redefine as your prefer the column and the data type

Comment: I mean, am I guaranteed to get always get the same type as I would get from `integer()`? Or is it depending of the database software (32-bit vs 64-bit machine, versions)? It would be bad if a `primaryKey()` internally maps to `BIGINT` for a specific database software and I use `integer()` (which maps to an `INT`) for all referencing columns as it worked for me on my test systems.
Do you get what I mean?

Comment: @DBX12  You could check better  in  yii2 pk data type reference docs .. but for what i remember the pk data type is integer(11) ..  and is used  as default for prumaryKey() function in table creation  ...  hope is useful  ..

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I hope the docs shed some light on the logic the type for the PK is selected.

Comment: Read the code and found, that `yii\db\mysql\QueryBuilder` specifies the primary key as `int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` so it is compatible with the definition of the integer with `int(11)`

Answer (score 2):

```
    $this->createTable('posts', [

        'post_id' => "bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT",

        'loc_id' => $this->integer(10)->unsigned()->notNull(),

        "PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`,`loc_id`)",

    ], 'ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8');
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
$this->createTable('new_table',[
        'id' => Schema::TYPE_PK.' NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT',
        'name' => Schema::TYPE_STRING,
        'age' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER
    ]);
```

However you can simply use the below style and **Yii** will replace the **'pk'** type of id based on your DBMS. for MYSQL it will be **int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY**

```
$this->createTable('new_table',[
        'id' => 'pk',
        'name' => Schema::TYPE_STRING,
        'age' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (imo more readable) approach is:

```
$this
    ->integer()
    ->unsigned()
    ->notNull()
    ->append('AUTO_INCREMENT');
```

Comment: That throws error `Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key` in mysql

Comment: `->append('AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY')` works fine in mysql